# Propper way of Error handling in a nodejs API server

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I need to handle errors in my API server on node.js.
I created a error handling module, which sends the errors (only in dev mode) to the API client in a JSON object similar to this:

```
{
    "status": "fail",
    "error": {
        "statusCode": 404,
        "status": "fail",
        "isOperational": true
    },
    "message": "no valid register found. Please provide a valid register",
    "stack": "Error: no valid register found. Please provide a valid register\n    at /Users/myUser/ITstuff/smarthome-heating/controllers/modbusController.js:77:21\n    at async /Users/myUser/ITstuff/smarthome-heating/controllers/modbusController.js:73:17"
}
```

now the problem I have is, that I need to create a new error in a submodule of my API controller when no case is true in the switch statement.

```
// this is the modbusHandler.setValue(doc, val, next) function
// 2) RUN PROGRAMMS
  let checkVal;
  switch (doc.register) {
    case 0:
      await client.writeCoil(doc.address + offset, !!val);
      checkVal = await client.readCoils(doc.address + offset, 1);
      break;
    case 4:
      await client.writeRegister(doc.address + offset, val);
      checkVal = await client.readHoldingRegisters(doc.address + offset, 1);
      break;
    default:
      throw new Error(
    'no valid register found. Please provide a valid register'
  );
  }
```

At this time, I handle it in this way:

```
// the function is wrapped in a try-catch statement
     const val = await modbusHandler.setValue(doc, req.body.value, next).catch((err) => {
                    console.log('here it is');
                    return next(new AppError(err.message, 404));
                  });


res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      val,
    },
  });
```

1. In the API controller, the function with the switch statement gets called
2. If no case matches the expression, then it throws a new Error
3. catch the error then call the custom error and respond error in a JSON format to the client

This solution works not really, I get a response error because there is no return for the function of the API controller. This causes a second response which is of course not good.

**My question is now: How can I solve this problem in the right way?**

Custom Error constructor:

```
class AppError extends Error {
  constructor(message, statusCode) {
    // this is the official error message rom the error it self, this message will be in the response.json for the client
    super(message);

    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.status = `${statusCode}`.startsWith('4') ? 'fail' : 'error';
    this.isOperational = true;

    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }
}

module.exports = AppError;
```

Custom Error handler:

```
module.exports = (err, req, res, next) => {
  err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  err.status = err.status || 'error';

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    sendErrDev(err, res);
  } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    sendErrProd(err, res);
  }
};


const sendErrDev = (err, res) => {
  res.status(err.statusCode).json({
    status: err.status,
    error: err,
    message: err.message,
    stack: err.stack,
  });
};
```

Comment: You may be able to get help quicker if you provide a little bit more context around the custom error handler. As written, it looks like your error handler is being used as middleware, which means that by the time it actually gets to the api route handler, your custom error handler would've already happened. Maybe show where you're actually `catch`ing the error

Comment: I catch the error from the `switch` statement with a `.catch` after the function call in the API controller. In this `.catch`, I return with a new custom error which gives the client a API response

Comment: and yes my error handler is used as a middleware `app.use(AppError);`
Maybe I need to mention, that the whole API controller function is wrapped in a try-catch block in which catch simply calls `next`.

Comment: So, if you're using the built in routing functionality of express, which I would assume is the case, the issue is that your error handling middleware is being run before the code ever gets to your API controller, so when the controller throws the error, it never gets back to the middleware, if that makes sense.

Comment: as far as I understand this, it goes this way: In the `modbusHandler.setValue()` the `switch` statement happens to be the default, which throws an error. This error gets catch where the function is called and executes `return next(new AppError(...` which is the global error handler who will give the client the response in JSON. the problem is that the code runs forward after the function call and comes to the point where the response comes which causes a second error because the AppError has had sent already a response. exactly this second error is what I try to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of throwing the error, perhaps want to throw it to next like this so it can be handled by the error handler.

```
export const yourFunction = async (req, res, next) => {
   .....
   // throw the error to your route Error handler 
   return next(new AppError('no valid register found. Please provide a valid register', 400)) 
}
```

Then after all your route declaration you should have an Error handler that looks something like.

```
app.use(ErrorHandler);
```

#### You may also need an error catcher

```
//catchAsync
module.exports = fn => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
      fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
    };
  };
```

Which you will wrap your route like this.

```
route.get('/path/', catchAsync(yourFunction))
```

If you create the catchAsync middleware, you will not need any Try/Catch in your routes at all, as all will be thrown to your error handler.

#### Update.

The small complain about node, or even javascript is about the error handling.  For every function of function of function called, if you choose to throw error, then you need to throw error of error of error. You keep bubbling up "throw error" and then it gets out of hand.

In your switch statement, I would recommend you to return a null.

then you test `if (!variable) return next(new AppError);

Helper functions should behave like a helper function, it should return true/false/null/value, and then you determine in your main function whether an error should be thrown or not.

This way you centralises your error.

Comment: I did it exactly as you mentioned. But I still get the error: `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`
this is because the function where the error gets thrown to the global error handler `app.use(ErrorHandler)` is in the function of the route. So I never return out of the function on the route. This causes the problem, that the function on the route goes further to the response and wants to send the response to the client. And there is where I get the header error. somehow I need to get out of the function on the route...